# A tool that can bookmark commands instead of doing reverse-i-search

Tags: command-line, command-line-tool

Not sure if such a tool exists or not

What I am looking for is a more sophisticated alias system. The goal is to find a tool that adds aliases to commands *with* description that would only work in a specific directory.

---

The current workflow for me is inefficient. I rely on hitting `<CTRL+R>` & I have a custom alias config.

Using custom aliases doesn't work well for me because:

- They are global
- They hide the command/don't have a readable description
- I end up opening the config file to read the description/command often

If a tool exists to solve some of these problems, please recommend it to me.